# Nlog - conditional layout based on message

Tags: nlog

I want nlog to output newline when message is empty, when message is not empty, I want output layout.
I've tried following approach, but it doesn't work:

```
<variable name="DefaultLayout" value="${time}  ${level:uppercase=true}: ${message}"/>
<variable name="Main" value="${when:when='${message}'=='':inner=${newline}:else=${DefaultLayout}}"/>
......
<target xsi:type="ColoredConsole" name="console" layout="${Main}" />
```

In this configuration it prints new line when message is empty, but when message is not empty, it doesn't print this message, only `16:06:34.7274  INFO`
How to fix config to have desired effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the colon (`:`) in the variable `DefaultLayout` with a backslash (`\`)

Comment: WOW! I saw this in docs, but thought that this is not necessary, since I'm not using direct layout, but reference variable instead. Thanks @Julian for the tip and thanks for your impressive work for Nlog!

Comment: thanks @Kai! FYI, variables are inlined when parsing the config, so they have the same rules as direct usages.